# My plugin wants to update another plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization

I am having issues when I view my installed plugin page, it's telling me there is a new version available. If I click the view version or view details links, it shows a completely different plugin that someone else put on wordpress.org.

I've tried changing the plugin name and uri, and everything should be unique so not sure why this is happening.

Has anyone had this happen or know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress retrieves the plug-in name from the comment block header in the main plug-in file (using the function `get_plugin_data` defined in `/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php`).

The thing is, it doesn't look for updates every time you visit the page - it schedules a cron job that fires every few hours to ease load on the servers running the repository.  So after it finds an update for a plug-in, it will cache that find.

My recommendation:

1. Deactivate and delete your plug-in from the site.
2. Re-name the plug-in in the code / rename the plugin folder.
3. Re-add your re-named plug-in to your site

This should circumvent any caching done by the update system.

[Copied Resource Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216696/3204142)

Comment: That fixed it. I renamed everything except for the folder name, and was still having the issue. I renamed the folder and it no longer points to the other plugin. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just to make it clear and precise - WP checks for updates based on slug (like: plugin-folder/main-plugin-file.php), not plugin name.